# how to prevent records from commit in odoo unit testing

Tags: unit-testing, odoo

While writing test cases in Odoo 10 custom modules, I'm using `self.env['test.model'].create({..})`, this is actually committing the records in DB instead of getting rolled back after the completion of test cases. I used `SingleTrasactionCase` and `TransactionCase` to write my test cases.

Can someone suggest to me the cleanup code I can add to prevent this from happening?

Below is my sample code:

```py
class TestModel(SingleTransactionCase):
     def setUp(self:
        super(TestModel, self).setUp()
        self.testMod = self.env['test.model'].create({..})

     def test_form_submit(self):
        self.testMod.form_submit()
        self.assertEquals(...)
```

Comment: In `TransactionCase ` the transaction is rolled back and the cursor is closed after each test and in `SingleTrasactionCase`, all test methods are run in the same transaction, the transaction is started with the first test method and rolled back at the end of the last..

Comment: thank you for your answer. I was able to sort the issue which is actually due to an existing code from different custom module.